# CSS3 vs Angular Material CSS

Tags: html, angularjs, css, angular-material

I have a ul, li design css which works good on bootstrap. When I use the same on Angular material project, Angular material css is blocking that css code to work.

css code:

```
li {
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    background: dodgerblue;
    margin: 0 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
}

    li::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: .9em;
        left: -4em;
        width: 4em;
        height: .2em;
        background: dodgerblue;
        z-index: -1;
    }


    li:first-child::before {
        display: none;
    }

.active {
    background: dodgerblue;
}

    .active ~ li {
        background: lightblue;
    }

        .active ~ li::before {
            background: lightblue;
        }
```

Html code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/style.css">
<link href="master/libraries/angular-material/angular-material.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

On including material css link, my design is not working as expected. But, I need that to get work.

Comment: try to place your css after angular-material css

Comment: i tried, but no fruits.. for that. I still remain the same. do angular material support css3?

Comment: why wouldn't it.remember angular is mostly a javascript framwork .It doesn't affect any CSS3 properies of your browser

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to add your css after angular material css like this:

```
<link href="master/libraries/angular-material/angular-material.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/style.css">
```